# Is it feasible to migrate from Jasmine/Karma to Jest?

Tags: angular, jasmine, automated-tests, jestjs

I have an Angular 7 app with 3300+ tests. And they take too much time to run and too much effort to maintain. I've heard a lot of good things about Jest but, not sure if migrating all of those tests from Jasmine to Jest is actually feasible.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, but I will say that `Jest` is based on `Jasmine` so that definitely reduces the level of effort since they behave similarly and share much of the same syntax.

Comment: 3300+ is a lot of tests to migrate. That's going to take you a might long time. I might be tempted to look at why those tests are slow and flaky before blaming the testing framework, because it's possible to make all the same mistakes in Jest.

Comment: Agreed that this question is broad and opinionated. Jest isn't different enough maintenance wise (I've used both and am back on Karma). "Feasible" depends on time, skill, budget, how well the first tests were written, and all that noise that doesn't allow anyone here to effectively answer that. Yes you _can_ migrate. I've started using ng-bullet and it helps a little with performance. One of the longest parts of running my tests is the compile. I've created a lot of project specific helpers to make tests a breeze to write (if you feel like you type / copy / paste often).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily answer this yourself by upgrading to jest.  There's a great walkthrough on [Github by the jest-preset-angular team](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular).

In your project root add a few files:

`setup.jest.ts` with:

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

`jest.config.js` with:

```
// Angular Ivy (9+ only for the next line)
require('jest-preset-angular/ngcc-jest-processor');

// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
};
```

`tsconfig.spec.json` with:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

modify `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "lib": [ "es2018", "dom" ],
  "esModuleInterop": true
```

modify `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
"types": [ "jest" ] // Replace "jasmine"
```

modify `package.json`

```
"test": "jest -c ./jest.config.js ./src
```

add required packages:

```
npm install jest jest-preset-angular @types/jest @angular-builders/jest
```

### Post install migration

You can then automatically [transform](https://jestjs.io/docs/migration-guide) your tests (to some degree) from Jasmine to Jest:

`npx jest-codemods`

#### Now you can answer your question for your particular project

Run:

`npm run test`

See how many failing tests you will need to manually fix to complete the migration.  And decide if this is within your timelines to do it.

#### Troubleshooting

> Error: cannot set base providers because it has already been called

Look for `tests.ts` file and remove it.  This is a karma file that you don't need in Jest.

Comment: In my case I renamed the test files so that they were not recognized as tests by the pattern recognition.  This let me distribute the work amongst all the engineers over time.